# C# reflection - check if a property gets a given field

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a class with a readonly property that gets the value of a field.

```cs
class Example 
{
    private readonly int _field;
    public int Property => _field;

    // constructor setting _field etc.
}
```

Can I use reflection to verify that a given property gets the value of a given field, given only the `Type` i.e. without checking any of the actual values?

Something like:

```cs
public static bool ReadonlyPropertyGetsField(Type type, PropertyInfo property, FieldInfo field) 
{
    // Checks property get method always gets value of field
}
```

I had tried getting all fields and properties of the class but couldn't see a way to actually check a property getter gets a given field's value.

Comment: Unless displaying that very information is your only goal here, using reflection to implement any other type of logic is a very bad practice. If you can specify what you're trying to achieve with it, maybe we can help you find a cleaner and more reliable solution to your problem.

Comment: I'm trying to test more or less what I described. Given a type, a readonly property and a readonly field, does the property always return the value of the field. It's for a verification test that checks for this behaviour and seeing as I could not find docs on the subject I was wondering if it was possible.

Comment: Properties are just a “pretty” method.  You will have to decompile the byte code within the methods and look for the field assignments... you aren’t going to want to do this.

Comment: If you are trying to perform static analyze on your code use Roslyn. https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers

Comment: I'm familiar with Roslyn but it's not an option for me here unfortunately.

Comment: Sounds like kind of a unit test, but usually they do _not_ test the internals of a class. What is the reason for this test, can the class not be tested enough by its public properties? And would it be possible to avoid the member at all `public int Property { get; private set; }`, then there is nothing which can go wrong and nothing to test.

Comment: The test needs to verify that the property gets a given field, regardless of what the value is. I agree adding private setters would be good but the fields are all `readonly`.